# Get previous,current and Next Record in ssrs report in a page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a report Which Show Previous,Current and Next id on Report. We can get Previous id via Preveious(Fields!Id.Value) but how can get next Id. Here is no function as Crystal report **Next(Fields!ID.value)** in ssrs. I am new in SSRS .Please  suggest me solution ?

[Here is screenshot to related this question](https://www.mindstick.com/Forum/34173/how-to-get-next-record-in-ssrs)

Comment: try this url http://sqlreportsq.blogspot.in/2012/03/can-we-get-next-row-value.html

Comment: There is a solution but it implies you have to add a row number column to the query that feeds your dataset. Edit your question to include the query.

Comment: Thanks alejandro zuleta . I have added rownumber now how will be do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a sample dataset with the row number by category, in your case it should be by ID.

[image]

Add a tablix and use this expressions.

[image]

For the `Next` column use.

```
=Lookup(Fields!Row.Value+1,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!Category.Value,"DataSetName")
```

It produces:

[image]

> Note that for the row number 1 there is no previous category so the
>   cell is blank, the same condition is present for last row number which
>   doesn't have a next category.

For your dataset it should be:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Row.Value+1,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!ID.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by your actual dataset name.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks alejandro zuleta. Now I am getting next record.