# Get Next Value within Row Groups in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem I'm trying to solve with getting the NextRow value but only within the specific RowGroup.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if Fields!Interventions.Value is not blank and nextrow(Fields!DateOccurred.Value) within the group is within 4 hours then Y else N
```

and another column:

```
if Fields!Interventions.Value is not blank compare currentrow(Fields!DateOccurred.Value) to nextrow(Fields!DateOccurred.Value) and display the differences in hours
```

But I'm stuck as to how i could do this expression from within SSRS.

I saw the following question:
[Get previous,current and Next Record in ssrs report in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385975/get-previous-current-and-next-record-in-ssrs-report-in-a-page) 
but the issue with this one is that it doesn't work with Row Groups in SSRS.

Upon further advise, it appears as this isn't possible to do in SSRS, but would be possible in the query itself.

This is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.PatientID, PL.ChartLocationID ORDER BY P.DateOccurred ASC) As Row#,
    R.NameFirst,
    R.NameLast,
    P.DateOccurred,
    CASE P.Interventions
    WHEN 1 Then 'Regular Analgesia'
    When 2 Then 'Heat Pack'
    When 4 Then 'Cold Pack'
    When 8 Then 'Massage'
    When 16 Then 'Exercise'
    When 32 Then 'Other'
    END as Interventions
FROM 
    ChartEntry P
LEFT JOIN ChartLocation PL on
    P.ChartLocationId = PL.ChartLocationId  
Inner Join Resident R on
    PL.ResidentID = R.PatientID 
where 
    P.DateDeleted is null and
    P.DateOccurred >= '01 Jul 2017' and
    P.DateOccurred < '01 Aug 2017'
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Here is some sample data showing the results for the extra two columns:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and better way is to use `LAG/LEAD` in your `SQL` to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Then use self-join or CTE to determine what you want? that depends on your SQL skills. Or you can always post the sample data, and members can suggest a solution. I don't think it's doable in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SSRS:

Set your detail value to `Previous(Fields!DateOccurred.Value)` and the detail row visibility to `= RowNumber("yourgroup") = 1` which will hide the first row.

Use one row on the group total, in order to display the last value by setting its value to `=Last(Fields!DateOccurred.Value)`

The date difference expression check for the detail will be

```
=Iif(
NOT(Fields!Interventions.Value Is Nothing) AND
DateDiff("h", Previous(Fields!DateOccurred.Value),Fields!DateOccurred.Value)>=4,
"Y",
"N"
)
```

and for the last line

```
=Iif(
NOT(Fields!Interventions.Value Is Nothing) AND
DateDiff("h", Last(Fields!DateOccurred.Value),Now())>=4,
"Y",
"N"
)
```

In the images below, the red line will be hidden with the visibility condition.
Your report will contain only the expected date column, I include the current row date for demonstration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What do you mean by = RowNumber("yourgroup") = 1 in terms of yourgroup? I updated the initial question after Viking's comment if that helps.

Comment: Replace "yourgroup" with the name of your group in the tablix. If there is no group but only detail "yourgroup" value should be the same as the tablix name.

Comment: @James I have also updated my answer to match the new field names

Comment: sorry, I'm totally lost with your solution. It should be looking at the Next DateOccurred and not the Previous DateOccurred. Your solution looks like using the Previous, not Next unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I know the workaround is a bit confusing. Suppose we have 10 rows as in my example. We display row1 data on row2, row2 on row 3,... and finally row10 on the total line. So the row2 previous date is actually row1 date, and row2 date is actually row1 next. Is it more clear now?